# PySpark how to generalize the read from Database

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Below is my code :

```
conn_url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//1xxx.xxx.xxxx.xx:1521/USER”

df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url",conn_url).option("drive","oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").option("dbtable”,”table_name”).option("user”,”user”).option("password”,”pwd”).load()
```

I wanted to write a generic function by which I can call the above code for different table names.
Basically all the options in spark.read.format will be same, just that table name will be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `conn_url` remove database name `USER`

**`conn_url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//1xxx.xxx.xxxx.xx:1521”`**

Now in `dbtable` provide the **`schema_name.table_name`** i.e **`USER.<tb_name>`** now spark will read the table from the `conn_url`

```
.option("dbtable”,”table_name”)
```

(Or)

Use [**`conf files`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46406176/what-is-the-best-pyspark-practice-to-load-config-from-external-file) and read the `conn_url and table_names` from the conf files, so that we don't need to change any code.